# Can I do SQL AG for read scale when both source and destination are FCIs?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2019

I am reading this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-clustering-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#WSFC

> Deploying Always On availability groups requires a Windows Server
> Failover Cluster (WSFC).

I have also read that a read scale (not HA) sql AG doesn't require WSFC.

I have 4 servers.

Server 1 and 2 are in FCI-A.

Server 3 and 4 are in FCI-B.

Assuming servers have enterprise edition license.

Can I configure read scale sql AG between FCI-A and FCI-B? That is - can both the sides (replica) of AG be FCI's?

Comment: Yes, you can if you mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, what does the following mean then  `An FCI can participate in an availability group as one of the instances hosting either a primary or secondary replica.` Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr?view=sql-server-ver16#always-on-failover-cluster-instances

Comment: It means that a member of AG can be either a single instance or a failover instance. For example I have mixed environments.

Comment: It says one of the instances can be AG. Not both. There are conflicting statement: `The instances participating in an availability group can be either standalone or Always On Failover Cluster Instances` and then later it says `An FCI can participate in an availability group as one of the instances hosting either a primary or secondary replica.`

Comment: "either standalone or Always On Failover Cluster Instances " means it is indifferent. I swear: I have an AG configured on top of 2 failover cluster instances.

Comment: In your situation did all the fci nodes reside in 1 wsfc? Or did you have 1 wsfc per fci?

Comment: Every AG is on a wsfc.. I don't get the question, sorry

Comment: In your case both fci and ag bong to same wsfc?

Comment: Yes. Only the DAG is on another FCI.